# Count Emails In Inbox Every Hour And Save To text file

Tags: vba, outlook

I'm trying to write some VBA in Outlook to count emails in the inbox folder (unread and read) every hour and to dump something like the below to a text file each time that happens:

28/02/2018 01:00 - 1,320

I've seen various code snippets, but I'm not sure how to achieve this. Could someone help please?

Comment: Could you be more specific? You have seen various code snippets... what was your exact problem with them? For example, you were unable to find code editor in Outlook or you were getting an error etc.

Comment: I can't find a code snippet that does this. Just one that counts emails from certain senders miroxlav.

Answer (score 1):

*Should be simple to do that-*

*Example*

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub example()
    Dim Items As Outlook.Items
    Set Items = Application.Session.GetDefaultFolder( _
                                    olFolderInbox).Items

    Debug.Print Now() & " - " & Items.Count

    Dim FSO As New FileSystemObject
    Dim TS As TextStream
    Set TS = FSO.OpenTextFile("C:\Temp\Emails_Count.txt", ForAppending, True)
        TS.Write Now() & " - " & Items.Count
        TS.Close
End Sub
```

---

[image]

Comment: Thank you this seems perfect, is there any way to make it run every hour or every time the inbox count changes?

Comment: @user1149620 create hourly outlook reminder see example https://stackoverflow.com/a/40144594/4539709