# Open MS Access and Fire Macro using MS Outlook

Tags: vba, ms-access, outlook

I did a bit of research and I think the best way to auto-fire a Macro is to use the AutoExec method in Access.

I believe the script below will do the job.

```
Option Compare Database

'------------------------------------------------------------
' AutoExec
'
'------------------------------------------------------------
Function AutoExec()
On Error GoTo AutoExec_Err

    DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdWindowHide
    MsgBox "Welcome to the client billing application!", vbOKOnly, "Welcome"
    DoCmd.OpenTable "Orders", acViewNormal, acEdit


AutoExec_Exit:
    Exit Function

AutoExec_Err:
    MsgBox Error$
    Resume AutoExec_Exit

End Function
```

My question, now, is what is the best way to trigger the event of opening the Access DB?  Unfortunately the Windows Task Scheduler has been turned off by my IT department (gotta love it).

I'm thinking there must be a way to get Outlook to open the Access DB as a Task, or some such thing.  I experimented with a few ideas, but haven't been able to get anything working.

Does anyone here have any idea how to do this?

To add a bit more color to this, basically I want to auto-import data from a remote SQL Server database, into Access.  As you may have guessed, the SQL Server Agent has been disabled too.

I am trying to run this job as a daily process, using Outlook, because that's really all I have available right now.

Comment: ...reminds me of [one of many of] my side projects, which I've been meaning to use as example with a Q&A on I'm planning on writing, *"Data entry to Access via SMS text messages"*..  For now I'll put together a quick answer for you, in a few mins,..

Comment: just example  https://stackoverflow.com/a/40144594/4539709

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would normally recommend Windows Task Scheduler but as you said, you don't have access to that (I'd still consider other alternatives for that - i.e. a third party scheduler or having IT add a scheduled task for you).

But if you must...

You can use an event in Outlook VBA to trigger code when a recurring Task reaches its reminder. In that event, you can open your Access database.

Caveats:

- You need to lower macro security in Outlook. You may not be allowed
  to do this and at the very least you should consider the
  ramifications of this.
- The processing in Access will block Outlook
  while it runs.
- The Task must have a reminder to trigger. The code
  below hides the reminder popup, but without setting a reminder, the
  event doesn't run.

This code must be in the `ThisOutlookSession` module within the Outlook VBA IDE:

```
Private WithEvents m_reminders As Outlook.Reminders

Private Sub Application_Startup()
    Set m_reminders = Application.Reminders
End Sub

Private Sub m_reminders_BeforeReminderShow(Cancel As Boolean)
    Dim reminderObj As Reminder
    For Each reminderObj In m_reminders
        If reminderObj.Caption = "MyDailyAccessImport" Then
            Dim accessApp As Object
            Set accessApp = CreateObject("Access.Application")
            accessApp.Visible = True
            accessApp.OpenCurrentDatabase "C:\Foo\MyDatabase.accdb"
            Cancel = True
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Then, in your database, use an `AutoExec` macro to do the processing you require.

Answer (score 2):

<sub>*For your IT team:*</sub>
 - Microsoft TechNet: **[Why You Shouldn’t Disable The Task Scheduler Service in Windows](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/askpfeplat/2013/07/14/why-you-shouldnt-disable-the-task-scheduler-service-in-windows-7-and-windows-8/)**

<sub>*...on the other hand, in I.T.'s defence:*</sub>
 - Slashdot discussion : **[Why Everyone Hates the IT Department](https://it.slashdot.org/story/11/11/26/2113231/why-everyone-hates-the-it-department)**

<sub>*...and for you:*</sub>
 - Stack Exchange: **[How can a developer can ask for more freedom from IT policies](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/35893/as-a-developer-how-can-i-ask-for-more-freedom-when-confronted-with-a-tight-it-s?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)**

---

Your question reminds me of [one of many of] my side projects, which I've been meaning to use as example with a Q&A on I'm planning on writing, *"Data entry to Access via SMS text messages"*.

It also reminded me of countless debates (battles?) of days gone by.  Forgive me as I go slightly off-topic in a rant,  *"Developers vs I.T."...*

---

I can't speak for everyone's situation, but in my opinion, some jobs worse than others for different departments defeating each other's work by doing their own jobs, and I figure there's a clear correlation, basically that *"the larger or more 'government-associated' the company is, the bigger the headaches"...*

**...     '     o̲n̲e̲   ?"**

Unfortunately unreasonable restrictions placed on competent developers, mandated by off-site management, can result in a bigger security hole than the "privilege" would have.

[image: IT vs I.T.]

---

### *Auto-execute a procedure in Access*

*Back to your question,* you have a few options to auto-run procedures in Access:

- Create an **`AutoExec` Macro**, with a single command: `RunCode`. It will automatically run when the DB is opened.  Instead of using the macro interface, you can just have a single command, that runs a VBA function.

  [image: AutoExec]

  Note that is has to be a `Function` (not a `Sub`) and the function must use zero parameters.  ([More info](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/create-a-macro-that-runs-when-you-open-a-database-98ba1508-dcc6-4e0f-9698-a4755e548124))
- Set a Startup Form in File > Options > Current Database, and then set the form's `Form_Open` procedure to call your code. ([More info](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/set-the-default-form-that-appears-when-you-open-an-access-database-94961011-392f-4c3b-8dbc-e5d5adbff1df))
- If the database is usually going to be open, you could use a form's Timer events to schedule one-time or recurring tasks.  I can't recall whether Access behaves like Excel, which (if you don't cancel a pending event before closing the application) will automatically re-open the application. ([More info.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/access-vba/articles/form-timer-event-access))
- Include the `/X:` switch when opening Access to specify the name of a macro to execute.  For example, on command-line or in a `.BAT` batch file or a desktop shortcut:

  `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\MSACCESS.EXE  /x:myMacro`
- Include the `/CMD:` switch when opening Access to specify custom options.  Then, within VBA, you can test the value of the switch, if any, with the `COMMAND` function.  For example:

  **Command Line:**

  `MSACCESS.EXE  /cmd:Take actions one and two`

  **VBA:**

  `If InStr(Command,"two") <> 0 Then`
  `'do action two`
  `End if`

Note that spaces are *allowed*, and therefore the `/CMD` must be the last switch used.

More about Office's [command-line switches](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/command-line-switches-for-microsoft-office-products-079164cd-4ef5-4178-b235-441737deb3a6#ID0EAABAAA=Access) and [Access's `Command` function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/command-function).

***<sub>...I think I'm missing another way (besides Task Scheduler), but maybe it will come to me.  Obviously, third-party application are another choice that I won't get into because I've never tried them.</sub>***

[image: monitored]

---

### *Run Access from Outlook*

You can set rules for emails with an action of `Run a Script`, which will call an Outlook VBA procedure, which can in turn open another file as necessary.  Outlook [tasks](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/outlook-vba/articles/taskitem-object-outlook) and calendar [appointments](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/outlook-vba/articles/appointmentitem-object-outlook) can also be coerced into running a script.

With these two options, you can set it up so your code runs at certain times, intervals, or even on certain actions occurring to any extent of complexity as you desire.

> <sub>**For example you could**</sub>:
>
> ***"Start procedure X when an email is received, but only if:
>
> - it was sent from my cellphone (as a [text-to-email](https://email2sms.info/)), and,
> - it contains a specific keyword in the subject line."***

<sup>(hence the basis for my "data entry via text messages" project I mentioned earlier!)</sup>

---

### More Information:

- **[Getting Things Done – Outlook Task Automation with PowerShell](http://www.leeholmes.com/blog/2007/03/01/getting-things-done-outlook-task-automation-with-powershell/)**
- **[How to Auto Create New Tasks When Receiving Specific Emails in Outlook](https://www.datanumen.com/blogs/auto-create-new-tasks-receiving-specific-emails-outlook/)**
- **[How can you schedule automatic emails in Outlook 2013 for every weekday at a fixed time?](https://www.quora.com/How-can-you-schedule-automatic-emails-in-Outlook-2013-for-every-weekday-at-a-fixed-time)**
- MSDN : **[Working with Outlook Events](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/outlook-vba/articles/working-with-outlook-events)**
- MSDN : **[Getting Started: Interaction between Office Applications](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/office-shared-vba/articles/getting-started-with-vba-in-office#interaction-between-office-applications)**
- MSDN : **[Using Visual Basic for Applications in Outlook](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/outlook-vba/articles/using-visual-basic-for-applications-in-outlook)**

[image: IT at work]

Comment: *** '     o̲n̲e̲   ?"*** `:-)` lol

Comment: None of my USB slots will read from any device at all.  You can charge your phone and that's it.  Everything is completely locked down in my office.  Often, I can't even do the job I was hired to do.  LOL.

Comment: @ryguy72 I've worked in places like that too.  It's sad and frustrating when a company goes overboard on security to the point that people can't work.  The best way for them to ensure a secure system is to have NO computers. Just pay everyone to stay in bed at home.  That will also reduce car accidents during the commute...

Comment: LOL!!  I love it!!  I'll be moving on pretty soon, so it doesn't even matter what they do.  Steve Jobs once said, "It doesn't make sense to hire smart people and then tell them what to to.  We hire smart people so they can tell us what to do."